# Setting up and using Python interface in GMAT?

Tags: python, gmat

I have managed to successfully setup and use the MATLAB interface in GMAT, with a combination of the [documentation](https://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/nightly/html/MatlabInterface.html) and [this](https://youtu.be/bemo7jOXmoA) helpful video, which gave me all the information I needed. Alas, that is not the case for the Python interface. I have found 3 main sources of information:

- [GMAT documentation explaining the Python interface](https://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2018a/html/PythonInterface.html)
- [GMAT documentation explaining the CallPythonFunction GMAT command](https://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2018a/html/CallPythonFunction.html)
- [GMAT's latest version's release notes](https://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/nightly/html/ReleaseNotes.html), which point out that the recommended Python version to use is 3.7 (I assume they mean [this one](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/))

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Download and install Python 3.7 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/), (the 64-bit version as I'm using the 64-bit GMAT version).
2. Add **/Python37** and **/Python37/Scripts** to the system Path variable.
3. Create a system environment variable called PYTHONPATH, and in it add **Python37/Lib/site-packages** and **/Python37**.

And then what? The documentation doesn't go into much detail into how to declare or call Python functions in the GMAT script. It implies something about creating .py file (without saying where to place it. The bin folder where GMAT.exe is?) with the example name PythonModule, which defines the PythonFunction functions we want to use, and then calling them in the script with this command:

**[output_argument[, output_argument]...] = Python.PythonModule.PythonFunction(input_argument[, input_argument]...)**

I tried to do the first example [here](https://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2018a/html/CallPythonFunction.html) and I get:
**** ERROR **** GmatBase Exception Thrown: The Moderator cannot create a Command type "CallPythonFunction", which implies that even if I had setup PythonModule.py correctly it wouldn't work, as GMAT does not detect the Python interface. This is confirmed by right-clicking on the Mission Sequence, and the CallPythonFunction command not appearing.

So, how can I get the Python interface to work and after that how do I use it?